# Can I create relationship for count?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two models

```
Post
  has_many :comments

Comment
  belongs_to :post
```

When I want display a list of posts and it's comment count. I usually include comments in the post like this .

```
Post.find(:all,:include => :comments)
```

To display a number of comment for post.

```
post.comments.size
```

Can I create a has_many relation which return count of comments ?

```
 has_one :comments_count
```

Can I include this relationship like this ?

```
Post.find(:all,:include => :comments_count)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rails has a counter cache which will automatically update a columns value based on the count of associated items. This will allow you to include the count when you return the posts object. Just add it to the belongs_to on comment.

```
Comment
  belongs_to :post, :counter_cache => true
```

You'll need to add a new integer column to posts for the counter:

```
class AddCounterCacheToPosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_column :posts, :comments_count, :integer
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

To answer you question, yes you can; but this is not the most efficient way to do it. Normally you add a column to `Post` called `comments_count` and you updated that column every `Comment` CRUD action.

Add the column:

```
rails g migration add_comment_count_to_post
```

Then in that migration add the following line:

```
add_column :posts, :comments_count, :integer, :default => 0
```

Then there are two way to handle it from here.

The first is a custom `before_save` and `before_destroy` in `Comment` model.

`app/models/comment.rb`

```
class Comment << ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :post

    before_save :update_comments_count
    before_destroy :update_comments_count

    def update_comment_count
        post.update_attribute(:comment_count, post.comments.count)
    end

end
```

The second way is to use Rails custom helper for this:

`app/models/comment.rb`

```
class Comment << ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :post, :counter_cache => true

end
```